# VSO Release — [error]API resource location [GUID Code] not registered on https://xxxxx.vsrm.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops, ms-release-management

**Release Definition:**

- Only one task: **Publish Artifact**, aiming at publishing a website.
- Artifact associated with a build under released mode.

**Error Message:**

> 2015-12-31T16:49:07.2877689Z Start: AssociateArtifact
>
> 2015-12-31T16:49:07.2977694Z ##[error]API resource location [GUID Code xxxxxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxx] is not registered on https://xxxxx.vsrm.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/
>
> 2015-12-31T16:49:07.2987695Z End: AssociateArtifact

Kindly please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please share the scenario you are trying to accomplish? As Daniel mentioned, publish artifacts/copy and publish artifacts tasks are meant to be used within the build workflow.

Once the artifact(s) are published in build, upon linking with Release, you can consume the artifacts. For example, in your build workflow, you can publish the *.zip package file for the website and it can be deployed using Azure Web App deployment task within Release.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation! I've been trying to publish IIS websites on local server, by agent, problem is, the "publish artifact" during build phase always produce everything, such as CSharp souce code, but if I try to publish from my Visual Studio, then the output looks much more like a normal website, any ideas? Let me know if I should mark your answer and then open up another question for you. Thanks again！

Comment: @Ree5un, publish artifact just produces a downloadable bundle of files specified as an input. If you are trying to produce an IIS website then you should apply appropriate msbuild arguments. For example, /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="<directory>"

Comment: Thanks so much Roopesh!

Answer (score 0):

"Publish Artifact" is for publishing **build** artifacts (e.g. binaries) to a build so that you can release them later, not for publishing those artifacts to, say, an Azure Web Application.